# Querying RDS database using apachea drill

Tags: amazon-rds, apache-drill

Hi Am trying to query my RDS database using apache drill. I have created the RDS configuration with driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. I would like to know the SQL query format to be used in apache drill to fetch the data from RDS database.

Answer (score 0):

This is ANSI SQL (2008 AFAIK):
https://drill.apache.org/docs/sql-reference/

Please take a look how to connect to RDBMS with Drill:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/